# Firebase returns the entire database even with setting ref url

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to setup Firebase's realtime database in my web app.

I have everything initialized properly and can connect to the database. However, when I try to fetch data, I get the **entire** database returned in the snapchat.

The code I have here is trying to determine if a key exists:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('cars/');

ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild('toyota')) {
        alert('exists');
    } else {
        alert('does not exist');
    }
});
```

This always displays the 'does not exist' dialog, so when I ran:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(snapshot));
```

I realized that firebase was fetching everything.

Here is the structure of my database:

```
{
"users": {
    "uid": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "balance": 500
    }
},
"cars": {
    "carid": {
        "name": "Name of Car",
        "cost": "250",
        "features": [
            "ac", "awd", "leather_seats"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Every request I make just returns the entire database, which is frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: Check the documentation [Read and Write Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) specifically the Listen For Value Events section:  value: Read and listen for changes to the *entire contents of a path*.  Then check out the [Work with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) and the child_added event: *This event is triggered once for each existing child*

Comment: If you can be more specific about what data you are trying to get... a single node with a single child? Iterate over all children of a node? Etc. We can provide a more specific answer.

Comment: I am trying to determine if a key under a specific root node exists. I.e. if one of the root nodes called 'cars' has a child node with the key 'toyota'. However, since I am having this issue, I cannot receive just the toyota node and its children as well, I get the whole database instead.

Comment: Post a snippet of your structure, as text please, no images.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/theryan722/479593715e70d883a850fa894af63a8a

Comment: It's best practice to include a snippet of your structure *in your question* as links change and get out-dated. They are also not searchable. Why can't you just query the cars node where brand equals toyota? [Work with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

Comment: Okay, I edited the question with the outline. Can I run that query once? I don't want to listen to changes, only fetch the information as it is at that time.

Comment: Yes! You can query once which will retrieve all of the nodes matching the query and will NOT attach an observer. There are a number of posts here to provide a variety of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason firebase had an entire duplicate of the database placed under the node, so in actuality I **was** fetching the data from the specific node, it just so happened that it contained a copy of the database.

What I'm curious about is to how this could happen, as I was under the impression that when you imported JSON into firebase, it overwrote the entire database.

Comment: I know this is old, but just realized that if you import a JSON from the emulator, it'll add it at the location you are currently viewing and not at root.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that at the time haha

Answer (score 0):

Hey try using the child method to access your nodes

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/cars');
```

Sorry there was some missing bits.

Comment: I get 'firebase.database().ref.child is not a function'
EDIT: I added () to ref and it worked, but I am still getting the entire database :(

Comment: Firebase still returns the entire database even with that.

Answer (score 0):

I retrieve data for a node in the following way, without the preceding or trailing slash. Check if the following works.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('cars');
```

Comment: Firebase is still returning the entire database.